# Get value attribute from jQueryUI Spinner

Tags: jquery-ui, spinner, return-value

So, this question is specifically for the attribute `value` from a jQUeryUI Spinner. I had attempted a number of different things in order to have it change, but the only thing that changes is `arial-valuenow`, which I actually don't care much for. In fact, if it could be removed, that would be optimal. I understand what aria attributes are for, however for this instance I need the correct attribute.

My current work is as follows:

```
$(function() {
$("#spinner").spinner({
min: 0,
max: 20,
step: 1,
start: 0,
spin: function(event,ui) {
var value = $($(this).attr("value")).val($(this));
}
}); 
});
```

I did look around this site and didn't really see anything related to my question. Any assistance you can offer is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

While I am not particularly happy with it, I did find the answer:

```
$(function() {
$("#spinner").spinner({
min: 0,
max: 20,
step: 1,
change: function(event,ui){
    $(this).attr("value",$(this).val());
}
});
})
```

It updates the value, yes, but unfortunately the problem (with my script which interacts with jQueryUI) was more complicated than I thought and I just wasted 6 hours on it.

Hopefully someone else can find this helpful though.

Comment: Doesn't the first example at http://jqueryui.com/spinner/ show you what you need? Specifically the `$( "#getvalue" ).click(function() {
      alert( spinner.spinner( "value" ) );
    });`

Comment: No. The problem is is that when the field is built, there is no value="", only it's ARIA counterpart, aria-valuenow. Even if you put value="" or whatever, the ARIA counterpart does not update the value attribute of the input--only the ARIA. I need the ARIA and the value to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSWER:

```
$(function() {
$("#spinner").spinner({
min: 0,
max: 20,
step: 1,
change: function(event,ui){
    $(this).attr("value",$(this).val());
}
});
})
```